# With FileVault: Yosemite starts with default desktop background

Tags: macos, filevault, wallpaper

Since enabling FileVault (I think only after I did that for my second hard drive), the desktop background keeps resetting to the default at every startup. It suffices to select another folder in System Preferences -> Desktop to make it switch back to the one chosen by me, I don't have to actually set it explicitly again.
Does anyone experience the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it just occurred to me that the answer is obvious: OS X cannot access my Wallpapers folder which is on the second drive, before I have entered the password for using the drive, which obviously happens after the desktop is rendered. Solution: Move the wallpaper to the boot drive.

Comment: I also experience the resetting of desktop background every time I restart and I only have internal storage.

Comment: And by 'internal' you mean only one hard drive or multiple ones which all are inside the computer?